# Why time is not updated into the text box from the date and time pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using moment js for me to pop-up the date and time calendar. I can choose both the date and time and click the apply button. The moment I click the apply only the date seem to be update into the text box but no time is appearing. What could be wrong. 
Here is my css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is the text box

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-prepend input-group">
    <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="beginDateTime" id="beginDateTime" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I define my javascripts.

```
<!-- daterangepicker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

Finally I have this codes to the settings.

```
<script>
            $(function() {

              $('#beginDateTime').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "timePicker": true

}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected");
});
        }) 
   </script>
```

Comment: Whats inside `daterangepicker.js`? It could be helpfull to set up an example. With the information provided it's almost impossible to guess what could be wrong.

Comment: Could you please show us your javascript.

Comment: I dont understand what is wrong with my question and being down vote

Comment: @empiric everything of my codes are based on this link http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: I have updated my codes and show I do the settings for date and time picker?